# How to disable the drawer from react navigation for a certain screen

Tags: react-native

I've seen a lot of stack overflow articles that suggest on how to do this however I tried all of them and none of them seem to work for my case.

***my target:***
 to be able to disable the drawer from all of my screens except my JobFeedScreen.

***What I already did:***
drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed, drawerLockMode: 'locked-open' 
I also tried to put it on the screen itself using

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { state } = navigation;
        const {} = state;
        return {  
          header: null,
          drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed' ( or drawerLockMode: 'locked-open')
        };

}
```

here are my codes

for my drawer
**AppNavigation.js**

```
//DRAWER NAVIGATOR
const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator({
JobFeed: {
screen: JobFeedScreenStack,
navigationOptions: ({navigation})=>({
  drawerLabel: 'Job Feed',
  drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <SimpleLineIcons name="briefcase" size={ Metrics.icons.tiny } color={Colors.heavyGray} />
  )
})
},
NotificationScreen: {
screen: NotificationScreenStack,
navigationOptions: {
  drawerLabel: 'Notifications',
  drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <Entypo name = "notification" size = {15} color = {Colors.heavyGray} tintColor={Colors.white}/>  )  
}
},
ApplicationsFeed: {
screen: ApplicationScreenStack,
navigationOptions: {
  drawerLabel: 'Applications',
  drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <Foundation name = "clipboard-notes" size = {15} color = {Colors.heavyGray} tintColor={Colors.white}/>  ) 
}
},



},
{
  initialRouteName: 'JobFeed',
  drawerPosition: 'left',
  contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent,
  drawerType: 'slide',
  drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed',
});
```

other codes in **AppNavigation.js:**

```
    // Manifest of possible screens
const AuthStackNavigation = createStackNavigator({
  LaunchScreen: { 
     screen: LaunchScreen, 
  },
  JobFeedScreen: {
    screen: JobFeedScreen,
  },
  FilterScreen: {
    screen: FilterScreen,
  },
  NotificationScreen: {
    screen: NotificationScreen,
  },
  ApplicationScreen: {
    screen: ApplicationScreen,
  }
}, 
{
  // Default config for all screens
  initialRouteName: 'JobFeedScreen',
})

     //JOB FEED SCREEN
 const JobFeedScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
   JobFeedScreen: {
     screen: JobFeedScreen,
  },
 })

//LAUNCH SCREEN
const LaunchScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  LaunchScreen: LaunchScreen,
})

//NOTIFICATION SCREEN
const NotificationScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  NotificationScreen: NotificationScreen,
})

//APPLICATION SCREEN
const ApplicationScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  ApplicationScreen: ApplicationScreen,
})

//FILTER SCREEN
const FilterScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  FilterScreen: FilterScreen
})

// MAIN NAVIGATION
const MainNavigation = createSwitchNavigator({
DrawerNav: DrawerNav,
AuthStackNavigation: AuthStackNavigation, 
})

export default createAppContainer(MainNavigation)
```

Comment: disable guester when you and disable menu click on your particular screen: <DrawerNavigator disableGestures={disableGestures} />

Comment: where would I be putting this and can you give me a clearer snippet of the code @Miteshjadav ? Thank you very much! :)